# How to get the duplicate key in a ToDictionary cast?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

i have to cast a list to a dictionary in my app but im getting an error saying that **"An item with the same key has already been added".** But it is a list with more then 5k objects and  i need to see wich objects are with the same key. Is there a way to do that?
In the message exception i cant get it, so i thought that i can do it using a foreach or something.
Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

EDIT:

```
   var targetDictionary = targetCollection.ToDictionary(k => k.Key);
```

This target collection is a generic IEnumerable, and the key i get from a thirdy party database so i do not have access to it. The solution is find the problematic object and tells the supplier about it.

Comment: What are the items in your list? How are you currently trying to turn the list into a dictionary?

Comment: Well you could use something like `Distinct` before `ToDictionary` to ensure that you don't have duplicates however your question doesn't provide enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @DanielBrückner I made and edit. Thanks

Comment: So you don't need the dictionary, you just want to know the items with duplicate keys, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use LINQ to catch the duplicates.  You can then process them as you wish.

**create a dictionary that doesn't contain the duplicates**

```
var duplicates = myList.GroupBy(x => x.SomeKey).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

var dictionaryWithoutDups = myList
    .Except(duplicates.SelectMany(x => x))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.SomeKey);
```

**create a dictionary that contains only the first of each duplicate**

```
var groups = myList.GroupBy(x => x.SomeKey);

var dictionaryWithFirsts = groups.Select(x => x.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.SomeKey);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var badGroups = collection.GroupBy(item => item.Key)
                          .Where(group => group.Count() > 1);

foreach (var badGroup in badGroups)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The key {0} appears {1} times.", badGroup.Key, badGroup.Count());

   forach (var badItem in badGroup)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(badItem);
   }
}

var goodItems = collection.GroupBy(item => item.Key)
                          .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
                          .SelectMany(group => group);

foreach (var goodItem in goodItems)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The key {0} appears exactly once.", goodItem.Key);
}

var dictionary = goodItems.ToDictionary(item => item.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for dups

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();   
foreach(string s in myList) if(!hs.Add(s)) Debug.WriteLine("dup: " + s);
```

Or you could change hs to Dictionary if you want to process

```
Dictionary<string, myclass> dl = new Dictionary<string, myclass>();    
foreach(string s in myList)
{
   if(dl.ContainsKey(s)) 
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("dup: " + s);
   }
   else 
   {
      dl.Add(s, null);
   }
}
```

I see you accepted a LINQ answer but LINQ is not going to out perform this.

Comment: @NathanA yes i just looked the up myself

Comment: You can simplify this to `if (!hs.Add(s)) { Debug.WriteLine("dup: " + s); }` because `Add` will tell you if the item was already present.

Comment: @DanielBrückner Agree but Dictionary.Add does not work that way and I wanted code to go both ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the duplicates you can use [`.ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead. It creates a `ILookup<TKey, TValue>` which is basically a read-only `Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>` where the duplicates are stored as the "value" in a collection.